# WCF and ref parameters

Tags: c#, wcf

I'm having strange issues with WCF and passing parameters as ref.

Let's say I have a Class:

```
Class MyClass 
{
     public string str;
}
```

And a code block like this:

```
List<MyClass> c = new List<MyClass>();
c.Add(new MyClass());
MyClass c2 = c[0];
```

If I then call a WCF method that should update the str-property of that class:

```
WCFService.UpdateStr(ref c2);
```

The c[0] and c2 are different - shouldn't they contain the same string in the str-property!? Is there something wrong in the WCF by ref function parameters?

Comment: Do you have a `[DataMember]` attribute on `MyClass.str`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, they shouldn't. A parameter passed by reference means that the object itself can be changed, and in the case of WCF calls, it is. When the call to `UpdateStr` returns, c2 is reference a different object instance.

The image below shows what is going on with this scenario.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for a very illustrative picture! This should definitely be taken into account when designing WCF applications!

Comment: This isn't limited to WCF. Any method whose parameter is marked with `ref` can change the object reference (I just happen to know that WCF *always* does that). This should be taken into account when designing any code which calls methods with `ref` parameters.